# change order of specific mongo records

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

in mongodb records are like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc1206610430cd000004"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc1306610430cd000005"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root1"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc2706610430cd000006"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root2"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc2806610430cd000007"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root3"}
```

i want to change order of records like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc2706610430cd000006"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root2"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc1206610430cd000004"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc1306610430cd000005"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root1"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc2806610430cd000007"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root3"}
```

and i have following information 
node to move

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc2706610430cd000006"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root2"}
```

move before which node

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5191fc1206610430cd000004"), "ancestry" : null, "name" : "root" }
```

How can i do this??

Comment: In the first code snippet, you are seeing the natural ordering of mongodb ( root, root1, root2, root3 ). Can you tell me the use case why you need the natural ordering of mongodb? Just for a note, you shouldn't rely on the natural ordering of mongodb because they can change if updates are happening in the system ( which will cause document move, changing the natural ordering everytime )

Comment: Any solution to do this? Rearrange that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that. You cannot change the order of records. They are sorted by objectId(almost). If you want to sort based on a parameter, then put it into your objects and sort by that parameter.